# Display category page number links for older posts

Tags: links

I was given a task to move the content and certain familiar navigation elements from an old WP-based website to the new one, based on the latest version of WP.

The blog page of the old site has the number links to the old posts near the bottom of the page:

How can I create the same links in TwentyTwelve category page?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that old site is *not* any version of WordPress.

Second, don't hack TwentyTwelve, make a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). if you hack it, your changes will be lost when the theme is updated.

Third, the easiest way to achieve pagination like that would be [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/).

Comment: Thank you, @vancoder. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Just out of curiosity, what prompted the "First" part of your response?

Comment: Removed. As to your question - I looked at the source. It is not WP.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it, @vancoder. Could you teach me, in the source, what were you particularly checking, to see if the site is WP-based?

Comment: Most obviously, there are no paths to wp-content. There are also links to pages with .htm extensions, which is highly unlikely in WP.

Comment: Actually, @vancoder, since you clearly know what you're doing, I have another question regarding the same page, mind if I send you the link to it? Would appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: Could you please take a look, @vancoder: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/sorting-posts-by-date-title-or-keyword